# Oracle SQL: LEFT JOIN -> GROUP BY COUNT(*) without incorrect count amounts

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this SQL query which is causing me to struggle a little bit.

```
SELECT c.Threat_Type, COUNT(*) FROM BORE.NormalToilet c
   LEFT JOIN BORE.EnragedToilet p on p.Toilet_ID = c.Toilet_ID
GROUP BY c.Threat_Type
```

Here's the output:

```
+--------------+--------+
| Threat Type  |  Count |
+--------------+--------+
| Portable     |   26   |
| Japanese     |    1   |
| Toilet       |    1   |
| Assassin     |    3   |
+--------------+--------+
```

Now here's the problem with this query:

1. There are, correctly, 26 vulnerabilities in our portable toilet firmware.
2. There is, incorrectly listed, 1 vulnerability in our Japanese toilet... there are no vulnerabilities, only requested features. This should say `0`, not `1`.
3. Same problem as above: Toilet features have no vulnerabilities.

If I try an `INNER JOIN`, it doesn't include the fields with `1`. This is the correct behavior (as there are no matches), however, I want it to say `0` instead of `1`. Using a `LEFT JOIN`, it just says `1`, which is heinously incorrect.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want `count(p.Toilet_ID)`

Comment: when you use `left join` the row would contain a `null` value in one of the columns. As you are doing a `count(*)` it would count the entire row. so you get `1`. Use `count(somecolumnname)` instead/.

Comment: I'm more concerned with how an enraged portable toilet has 26 vulnerabilities. Or what an assassin toilet might be...

Comment: Can't believe I missed that... thanks.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name or `vkp`, if you're interested in getting a correct answer checked, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Credit to a_horse_with_no_name and vkp in the comments. If they do end up posting their own answer, feel free to vote to delete this answer.*

Instead of `count(*)` which counts *rows*, you want `count(p.Toilet_ID)`, which only counts the rows where `p.Toilet_ID is not null`.